# How to fix this broken crypto protocol?

Tags: cryptography, protocols, rsa, one-time-pad

I am considering a protocol where you upload a one time pad to a server, using public key encryption and then the result (using the pad) is sent back in plaintext:

```
Alice uses Bobs RSA public key to request a file
Bob replies over RSA that it is 7MB
Alice uploads 7MB of random bits to Bob encrypted by RSA
During this, Bob is responding with the plaintext of (file xor random data)
```

So I tried to run through the basic attacks to see if this was secure and I had to add:

```
The response must be divided into blocks and each block signed
otherwise Eve could modify the data on the way back from Bob to Alive
```

but then I realized Eve could modify the encrypted OTP on the way to Bob - this would not allowed her to edit the message reliably but to corrupt it. So we need to add:

```
 Alice should provide a checksum for each block of the OTP sent
```

So I tried to harden it up a little bit and I was wondering if there are any attacks against this?

Comment: The whole idea is absurd. The only reason to use OTP is its provable security, which you waste when you use RSA to send the pad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you are making a toy protocol for the fun of it -- learn about crypto, have fun implementing something, but understand that this toy scheme is probably flawed and that if you have sensitive data you should use well-known vetted protocols, not toy schemes you just came up with.  (If not see reasons [to not roll your own](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/18198/2568) ).

---

First, RSA just describes the scheme `c = m^e mod N` where you encrypt a message m with a public key `(N,e)`, and decrypt with private key pair `(N,d)`via `m = c^d mod N`.  You should not encrypt your OTP with RSA -- it will be very inefficient and there are many attacks against RSA without proper padding.  You really should always use padding schemes like [OAEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAEP) (specifically [PKCS #1v2](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-1/pkcs-1v2-1.pdf)).  RSA is expensive for long messages, in practice you always use hybrid encryption.  That is use RSA to encrypt a randomly generated key for a symmetric encryption function like AES (other encryption functions are fine, just chose AES for concreteness).  So Alice first sends E<sub>RSA</sub>(RSA-PubKey, OAEP(Random-AES-key)), where RSA-PubKey = (N,e) and E<sub>RSA</sub>(RSA-PubKey, m) = m<sup>e</sup> mod N.  Then she sends the AES-encrypted secret data E<sub>AES</sub>(Random-AES-Key, Secret-Data), which just means `Secret-Data` is encrypted with AES and the recently generated Random-AES-Key.  Then the receiver first decrypts the AES-key using RSA with the private key (N,d) and then undoes the OAEP padding, and then decrypts the message using that AES-key to get back the secret data.

That said, *checksums* should not be used to prevent tampering of a message in transit.  If an attacker can guess a message, they can calculate the checksum, and then tamper the encrypted message to alter both the message and checksum.  For example, if the message was encrypted with AES-CTR mode and the message is `m = "Transfer $1000 from Alice to Bob's account."` and uses MD5 hash as checksum `h=b2a26c14a029b0a2aadba4fa2ecd32d2`.  Eve could calculate xor between that message and `m' = "Transfer $9999 from Alice to Eve's account."` which has the md5 checksum `h' =308b23cb47b0efff365c2593e0a005d7` and then XOR the encrypted message with `m XOR m'` and the encrypted checksum with `h XOR h'`.

[Message Authentication Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) are the way to provide integrity that your message wasn't tampered.  These are essentially checksums that intrinsically rely on a shared secret key.  There's always a question of how to MAC, should you Encrypt-then-MAC -- (send `E(Data) ++ MAC(E(Data)`) or MAC-then-Encrypt (send `E(data ++ MAC(data))`) or Encrypt-and-MAC (send `E(data) ++ MAC(Data)`), but [Encrypt-then-MAC is the consensus best option though other schemes can be secure for certain ciphers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/205/1501).

There are other issues (e.g., generating OTP is quite expensive and uses a lot of entropy which could be problematic).  I also don't see what the OTP step gains in security -- e.g., if the RSA step is compromised all the other data is compromised as well to any eavesdropper.

Furthermore, the one-time pad only has provable security when the pad is used exactly once.  The many-time pad is notoriously weak as c1 XOR c2 = m1 XOR m2.  E.g., assume Eve can't send requests for files to Bob, that there's some undisclosed authentication function that verifies Alice's identity to Bob before Bob will respond back with a file encrypted via a OTP).  If she observes Alice ask for file1, sending an encrypted 7 MB OTP (OTP1), she could then request file2 (only 6 MB) sending back the same first 6 MB of OTP1.  Bob then replies back with file2 XOR OTP1, leaking to Eve the XOR of file1 and file2.  So along with the OTP that is MAC'd, there must be a scheme with a random nonce (generated by the server) that must be included with the encrypted OTP, that is verified (to make sure the encrypted pad wasn't replaced with a previously used OTP).